# MongoDB - Como inserir um ObjectID via variável?

Tags: mongodb

Estou aprendendo `MongoDB` e me surgiu um problema, estou tentando inserir um ObjectID em um array via variável, mas não estou conseguindo. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```js
> var aluno = db.alunos.find({"nome" : "leandro"});
> aluno;
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ada02cc6c0218c2b64e0214"), "nome" : "leandro", "data_nasc" : ISODate("1996-07-19T03:00:00Z") }
```

Agora na hora em que tento inserir apenas o campo "_id" ocorre o seguinte:

```js
> db.professores.update({"nome" : "leandro"}, {$push : {"alunos" : aluno["_id"]}}) 
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.professores.find({ })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad55f59f034bcd625334947"), "nome" : "leandro", "curso" : "guitarra", "alunos" : [ undefined ] }
```

O valor inserido é "undefined". O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score -1):

```
Model Alunos = {
nome:String,
data_nasc:Date}

Model Professores = {
nome: String,
curso: String,
alunos[{
 id:{
 type: Schema.Type.ObjectId
 ref:'Alunos'
}
}]
```

você pode passar uma array de objetos

depois na function e tipo isso

```
var aluno= {
 "nome":[{
 "id":"afafg1321faqf"
}]
}

db.Professores.findOneAndUpdate({nome:"Leandro"},{$Push:{alunos:alunos}})
```